# Change the colour and size of my HTML Eventbrite button

Tags: html, css, eventbrite

Eventbrite have given me an HTML code button to embed onto my Thrive Architect website which I have done. However, the button is tiny, and grey, and doesn't stand out. So I need to change the colour of the button to green and I need to make the size of the button bigger. Also I'd love to make the font bold.

Here is the code they gave me, which I need to customise (I have been trying to customise it for over 24 hours, done extensive research and tried it my way but whenever I change anything in the code and I save it, this appears next to the button `"[/tcb-noscript]`

```
<!-- Noscript content for added SEO --> <noscript><a href="eventbrite.co.uk/e/…" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"></noscript> <!-- You can customize this button any way you like --> <button id="eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-57878905364" type="button">Buy Tickets</button> <noscript></a>Buy Tickets on Eventbrite</noscript>
<script src="eventbrite.co.uk/static/widgets/eb_widgets.js"></…> <script type="text/javascript"> var exampleCallback = function() { console.log('Order complete!'); }; window.EBWidgets.createWidget({ widgetType: 'checkout', eventId: '57878905364', modal: true, modalTriggerElementId: 'eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-57878905364', onOrderComplete: exampleCallback }); </script>
```

Comment: *"I'll post the code in comments section"* - why?!

Comment: Jon, because it would not let me post it in the actual question!! It said "code not properly formatted" and refused to let me post the question

Comment: So **format the code correctly**, don't post it in comments where it's even worse. Read the handy [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), for example.

Comment: Thank you, it's literally like reading a foreign language, I know absolutely nothing about HTML codes!

Comment: Ahh if I knew how to format it, I wouldn't have reached out :) was hoping somebody could really help me by writing out what's missing from the code in regards to colour, font, and size

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service, if you want to change the HTML and CSS to restyle that button, look up introductory tutorials

Comment: Ok... thanks for your response. I've been reading tutorials for over a day and trying it myself and my way didn't work, and I came across SO after googling this question and I came across another question that someone else posted in regards to changing colour to their Eventbrite button, and the person who responded gave them the exact code with the changed colour which I felt was very helpful, but when I applied it to my code, it wouldn't work. So was hoping for someone to help me as they helped the other person on the other post, but no worries, thanks.

Comment: The button has an ID, so you can define CSS styles that apply specifically to that element in your web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add some CSS that targets this element. Grab the ID of the button, and include underneath how you want your button to look like. Like so:

```css
#eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-57878905364 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML only cut down for the example -->
<button id="eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-57878905364" type="button">Buy Tickets</button>
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH to the last answer, you're a star, I've been struggling for over a day, non stop, morning and night. I copied and pasted yours and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Webby No problem, glad to be of some help. :-)